# error C2057 with HANDLE

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I try to compile [flushmem.cpp](http://chadaustin.me/download/flushmem.cpp) with ms visual c++ 2008, but obtain error:
.\flushmem.cpp(69) : error C2057: expected constant expression
at line:
HANDLE processes[processCount];
and a warning:
.\flushmem.cpp(63) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'unsigned __int64' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
at line:
unsigned processCount = (totalPageFile + approximateProcessConsumption - 1) / approximateProcessConsumption;

how to solve?

Comment: No external code. Please include a minimal reproducible test case in your question...

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio 2008 compiler does not support a variable as the size of an automatic array. In the line:

```
 HANDLE processes[processCount];
```

**processCount** is a variable and the compiler will only accept a constant. You will need a C99 compliant compiler or you need to change the above line of code to allocate the array. For instance:

```
HANDLE* processes = new HANDLE[processCount];
```

If you allocate the array you will also need to delete it when you are done with it:

```
delete [] processes;
```